# Объединенный запрос выводит только один массив данных

Tags: php, массивы, mysqli, select, php7

Из базы данных нужно вытаскивать отдельно данные для ip с которого идет запрос и вытаскивать данные отдельно для email, который приходит из формы.

Имеется такой запрос:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `or_auth` AS one WHERE `ip` = '127.0.0.1' 
                        UNION
                      (SELECT * FROM `or_auth` AS two WHERE `email` = 'test@bk.ru')";//В базе данных есть такой емайл и есть такой ip
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); 
   print_r($row);
}
```

При данном запросе выводит только первый запрос:

```
Array ( [id] => 89 [ip] => 127.0.0.1 [email] => [date] => 1496507320 [col] => 1 )//Для ip поле email всегда пустое
```

а второй запрос не выводит. Как его вывести, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Для ip нужно выполнять одни действия после того, как придет результат, а для емайла другие. Также интересует, как можно обращаться к результатам по ip и отдельно по email? Возможно по ключу...

Comment: SELECT * FROM `or_auth` AS one WHERE `ip` = '127.0.0.1' OR `email` LIKE 'test@bk.ru'

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan Дает ровно такой же результат.

Comment: если так не выдает `LIKE '%test@bk.ru%' `,  Ну значит нет такого емейла

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan Емайд есть такой, я смотрю на него в БД:) А в `Array` должно быть вообще 2 результата при выводе `print_r($row);`? Если напрямую в БД писать запрос ваш, то выходит как раз 2 строки. И в моем примере тоже напрямую выводит также 2 строки.

Comment: Вот этот запрос у вас дает результат ? `SELECT * FROM `or_auth` AS two WHERE `email` = 'test@bk.ru'`

Comment: Упс извиняюсь `print_r (mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))`  дает естественно один результат.Его надо в цикле получать .А результат там есть естественно.Щас ответ оформлю

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan Да, дает напрямую в базе данных. Я пытаюсь выводить так: `print_r($row['email']);`, так выводит пустоту при имеющемся ip и емайле в базе данных, а как только удаляю из БД строку с `ip` = 127.0.0.1, то `$row['email']` сразу возвращает результат = `test@bk.ru`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш `SELCT ... UNION ...` равносилен Этому ,но боле оптимальному варианту :

```
SELECT * FROM or_auth AS one WHERE ip = '127.0.0.1' OR email LIKE 'test@bk.ru'
```

Если попытаться вывести **[mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)** без цикла то он вернёт только один столбец.

Решение:

```
//.........
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    print_r($row);
    if($row['ip'] && $row['email'])
    { //Оба есть.Соответствующие действия}
    elseif($row['ip'])
    { //Соответствующие действия}
    elseif($row['email'])
    { //Соответствующие действия}
    else
    { //Оба пустые.Соответствующие действия}
}
//.........
```

Можно и так :

```
for ($set = array (); $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); $set[array_shift($row)] = $row);

print_r($set);
```

> Также интересует, как можно обращаться к результатам по ip и отдельно
>   по email?

Eсли в выборке эти колонки участвуют то в результирующем массиве они будут ключами массива.

Выбирайте который вариант вам нужен.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо Вам!:) А вот как теперь, если в базе данных есть такой ip, то соответственно для него вылезут данные из бд, как к нему обратиться, выполнить для него какие то действия? И также соответственно, если есть емайл такой, то ему выполнить свои действия.

Comment: @Дима Это уже другой вопрос и к этому не  относится Задавайте по нему новый и скиньте мне ссылкуА если мой ответ решил ваш вопрос то поставьте пожалуйста галочку возле ответа Спасибо.

Comment: В вопросе моем этот вопрос прозвучал:) Хорошо сейчас оформлю.

Comment: @Дима  Я обновил ответ..Сегодня какой то рассеянный :) Спасибо

Comment: Очень Вам благодарен! Спасибо большое! Желаю Вам больших успехов!

Comment: @Дима Спасибо. И вам того же.

Comment: Заметил следующее:
1. Если указывать просто `if($row['ip'])`, то в `else` условие тоже срабатывает, пришлось сделать так `if(isset($row['ip']))`. 
2. Но теперь для этого блока, действие выполняется 2 раза, то что видимо 2 строки результата из запроса SELECT получается, по while проходит видимо то что. Даже не знаю должно ли так быть. Задать новый вопрос? Хотя зря сделал `if(isset($row['ip']))`, теперь, если ip нет такого, то условие else не срабатывает.

Comment: @Дима По моему не надо,второй `if` замените на `elseif`.Это получается что если у вас есть `ip` то делаем что то не смотря есть ли емейл.Или наоборот.Если ваши пожелания больше то задавайте

Comment: У меня надо так: если есть емайл и ip то выполнить для них обоих свои условия, а если кого-то из них нет, то выполнить другое действие для того которого нет. Я вообщем потом задам вопрос, скину Вам ссылку, если будет у Вас время, посмотрите, пожалуйста. На сегодня мне хватит, пойду отдыхать.

Comment: @Дима Обновил ответ